# use styling like span in textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have a textarea that can have some simple styling like spans in a paragraph. But the problem is that no html tags are allowed in textarea. So what should I do to have a textarea that can have some simple styling like coloring a sentence?

Comment: You can't. You're probably looking for `contentEditable`.

Comment: Its a bit off a pain to do, have you thought about using an editor like tinymce http://www.tinymce.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some RichText editor controls. There are many free ones available.

http://ckeditor.com/

http://www.tinymce.com/

More items in this links

1) http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors

2) http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/