# How to customize span into textarea?

Tags: html, css, input

```
<textarea>Some text. This is <span class="hashtag">#sparta</span></textarea>
```

span#hashtag displays as

```
<span class="hashtag">#sparta</span>
```

But I need to display it like "#sparta" with some styles.

How?

**UPD:**

@undefined [it's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621447/use-styling-like-span-in-textarea) not enough. I don't need RichText editor.

Comment: this may helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621447/use-styling-like-span-in-textarea

Comment: And this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12831101/format-text-in-a-textarea

Comment: @AmanVirdi, thanks for second link.

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize any span or other in textarea.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement